# Is a convergent sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Is the sequence $\{z_n\}\subset \mathbb{C}$ defined by

$$z_n=\cos\left(n\frac{\pi}{3}\right)+i \sin\left(n\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$$

a convergent sequence?

Comment: Hint: it's periodic of period $6$.

Comment: could you give me the reference of a text?

Comment: Could you elaborate? A text on what?

Comment: text on this subject, sequences of complex numbers

Comment: Try to mark first members of the sequence at the complex plane. They turns as a squirrel in a wheel!

Comment: evaluated for n = 0,1,2, ..... ? so?

Comment: Not sure it's what you are looking for, but "A Collection of Problems on Complex Analysis" by Volkovyskii et al., and "Problems and Theorems in Analysis" by Polya & Szegö, are very good. But maybe a book on introductory calculus would do?

Comment: Ok, you evaluated, so didn't you remark they repeat after $n=5$ ? How could there be a limit then?

Comment: its true!, after n = 5 repeats (zn)  = 1,-1

Comment: and this shows that (zn) converges to those two numbers?

Comment: No for both your statement and question.

Comment: Most definitions of convergence require that there be only 1 number that is converged to. What definition are you using?

Comment: @user115213 : if it did, both the real parts and the imaginary parts would have to converge.  Neither does.  Take your pick - show that the real pars diverge or that the imaginary parts do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Euler's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), we have
$$
z_n=e^{\pi in/3}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
|z_n-z_{n+1}|
&=\left|e^{\pi in/3}\left(1-e^{\pi i/3}\right)\right|\\
&=\left|1-e^{\pi i/3}\right|\\
&=1
\end{align}
$$
[To be convergent, a sequence must be Cauchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Cauchy_sequences). If $z_n$ were [a Cauchy sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence#In_a_metric_space), we would need $|z_n-z_{n+1}|\to0$.

Comment: could you send me the link of the theorem that says: If $z_n$ were convergent, we would need $|z_n-z_{n+1}|\to0$.

Comment: @user115213: Do you know the definition of [a convergent sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Cauchy_sequences)?

Comment: I'm looking in my book but I can not find this theorem.

Comment: @user115213: I have added links in the answer that should be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

No.  It has a subsequence that converges to $1$, and a subsequence that converges to $-1$.  For any positive integer $k$, $z_{6k} = 1$, so there is a subsequence converging to $1$, and 
$z_{6k+3} = -1$, so there is a subsequence converging to $-1$.  If the sequence $(z_n)$ converged, then all subsequences of it would converge, and they would all converge to the same number.

You don't really need any complex analysis, just trigonometry and some understanding of what it means for a sequence to converge.

Comment: As good as any reason :-) (+1)